# Element wise dataframe comparison and performing of conditional operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

Suppose i have these 2 dataframes:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b'], data = [[1,2],[3,4], [5,6],[7,8]])
b = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b'], data = [[1,2],[7,4], [9,6],[11,8]])
```

What i want to do is to compare each element of `a` with each element of `b` and if there's a match, then add +1 to the counter, if there isn't a match, i want to append the unmatched row to the empty dataframe above.

This is my code so far:

```
counter = 0
counts = pd.DataFrame()

for i, j in a.iterrows():
    for a, row in b.iterrows():

        if a[j] == b[row]:
            counter += 1

        else:

            counts = counts.append(a[row])
```

when i run it, i get into this error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

How could i get this done and fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: could you also show us the final expected dataframe? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simple using `merge` with `indicator`

```
s=a.merge(b,indicator=True,how='outer')
s
Out[481]: 
    a  b      _merge
0   1  2        both
1   3  4   left_only
2   5  6   left_only
3   7  8   left_only
4   7  4  right_only
5   9  6  right_only
6  11  8  right_only
```

Your count

```
s['_merge'].eq('both').sum()
Out[482]: 1
```

New df

```
newdf=s.loc[s['_merge']=='right_only',:].copy().drop('_merge',1)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It seems to do the job, but, is there a more elegant way to add +1 to the counter?

Comment: @Miguel2488 what you mean add + 1 ? `s['_merge'].eq('both').cumsum()`, like this  ?

Comment: something more like adding +=1 to the counter variable if the condition is fulfilled

Comment: @Miguel2488 if you do need a counter , you can using for loop with the result after merge , just when the '_merge' is equal to 'both' add 1 to the counter

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is use a mask (always avoid `for` loops in pandas when possible):

```
m = (a==b).apply(np.all, axis=1)   #assuming you want both elements to be equal
counts = a[~m].copy()
counter = m.sum()
```